# Javascript array problem: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to write some application in javascript and I am facing a problem with arrays.

I have the following code

```
var levels=new Array(),level={};
level.id=1;level.name="Суперваизер";level.url="supervisor";
levels.push(level);
level.id=2;level.name="Торговый представитель";level.url="agent";
levels.push(level);
level.id=3;level.name="Группа продукта";level.url="pg_group";
levels.push(level);
level.id=4;level.name="Категория продукта";level.url="pg_category";
levels.push(level);
level.id=5;level.name="Торговая марка";level.url="pg_trademark";
levels.push(level);
level.id=6;level.name="Продукт";level.url="product";
levels.push(level);
level.id=7;level.name="Регион";level.url="region";
levels.push(level);
level.id=8;level.name="Типы т.т.";level.url="outlet_type";
levels.push(level);
level.id=9;level.name="Торговая точка";level.url="outlet";
levels.push(level);
level.id=10;level.name="Тип оплата";level.url="payment_type";
levels.push(level);
level.id=11;level.name="Филиал";level.url="filial";
levels.push(level);
level.id=12;level.name="Экспедитор";level.url="expeditor";
levels.push(level);
level.id=13;level.name="Участник проекта";level.url="action_type";
levels.push(level);

//select
var select='<select>';
for(var i=0;i<13;i++){
  var option='<option value=' + levels[i].id + '>' + levels[i].name + '</option>';
  select+=option;
  }
select+='</select>';
```

This code gives me error in browser saying:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

How can I use array for this situation?

Comment: There's a big problem in this code : it always sets the same level object.

Comment: Rather than creating one object literal and continually overwriting it (which is affecting all the other instances which are already pushed into the array). push a new blank object literal in each time. `array.push({ id:1, name:"first one" })` etc.

Comment: The issue lies in code you haven't shown. The code above won't trigger the error you're describing. (It has the big issue dystroy mentioned, but that won't cause the error above.)

Comment: Voting to close as "can't be reproduced"

Comment: It isn't the problem, but here's a much better way to create that array (and doesn't have the issue dystroy mentions above): http://pastie.org/9326267 Or of course you could use a constructor to avoid retyping the property names repeatedly.

Comment: You received a warning when you tried to write your title, didn't you? Please, follow the tips the system is providing you.

Comment: thank u guys you were very helpful. brasofilo maybe i received or maybe not but next time i will be more careful but i appriciate your reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @dystroy, you use the same `level` object everytime and you modify it instead of creating a new one.

Anyway, you can simplify it with this syntax :

```
var levels = [
    {id: 1,  name: "Суперваизер",            url: "supervisor"  },
    {id: 2,  name: "Торговый представитель", url: "agent"       },
    {id: 3,  name: "Группа продукта",        url: "pg_group"    },
    {id: 4,  name: "Категория продукта",     url: "pg_category" },
    {id: 5,  name: "Торговая марка",         url: "pg_trademark"},
    {id: 6,  name: "Продукт",                url: "product"     },
    {id: 7,  name: "Регион",                 url: "region"      },
    {id: 8,  name: "Типы т.т.",              url: "outlet_type" },
    {id: 9,  name: "Торговая точка",         url: "outlet"      },
    {id: 10, name: "Тип оплата",             url: "payment_type"},
    {id: 11, name: "Филиал",                 url: "filial"      },
    {id: 12, name: "Экспедитор",             url: "expeditor"   },
    {id: 13, name: "Участник проекта",       url: "action_type" }
];

var select = '<select>';
for(var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    select += '<option value=' + levels[i].id + '>' + levels[i].name + '</option>';
}
select += '</select>';
```

Comment: While this is true, it clearly isn't the OP's problem. (It's much better code, though.) The OP's stated error isn't replicated by the code he/she quoted, the question cannot currently be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous objects and push them into array

```
levels.push({ id: 1, name: "Суперваизер", url: "supervisor" });
```

And I suggest using your array length in `for` loop rather than hardcoded value:

```
for(var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++){
    //do work
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52hhf/)

Comment: While that's true, it's not the OP's problem. In fact, the code quoted by the OP (although it has a big problem) doesn't exhibit the behavior the OP says it does.